# How to erase reverse_iterator correctly when erase and push_back happens?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a list container, which looks like:

```
std::list<int> l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

i often erase elements, so i choose `std::list`.

but, i also want to find the elemnt in O(1), so i record the reverse_iterator.

For Example:

```
  l.push_back(9);
  auto s = l.rbegin();  // record the iterator of 9, in order to erase it in the future fastly.
  cout << *s << endl;
  l.push_back(10);
  auto s2 = l.rbegin();
```

but when i erase like this:

```
l.erase(std::next(s).base());  // s the iterator of 9, in my brain
```

i want to erase 9, but actually, it erase 10.

I have two questions:

why i should use `next`? actually my `*s` can get the element, which is different with `.end()`.

how can i make the erase happen in my previous saved iterator?

Comment: `so i record the reverse_iterator.` Why don't you just record an `iterator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l.rbegin().base() == l.end(), which is not the position of the last element, but the end of the list. and `push_back` again won't affect this existing iterator, it is still pointing to the end of the list.

Then std::next(l.rbegin()).base() == l.end() - 1, which now is pointing to the last element `10`.

So if you want to remember the position of the `9`, you better use a normal iterator instead of a reverse one, or, use a reverse iteractor whose base pointing to `9`, and that should be `auto s = std::next(l.rbegin())`, and erase it as `l.erase(s.base())`.

the rule is `&*r == &*(i-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Since the iterator of the `list` is a bidirectional iterator, instead of using `reverse_iterator`, you can just use `--l.end()` to get the last valued iterator.

```
std::list<int> l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
l.push_back(9);
auto s = --l.end(); // record the iterator of 9
l.push_back(10);
l.erase(s); // erase the iterator of 9
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/zEnPfbv45)